# Generics and Varargs

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

In class we create two identical methods which has differences only in parameters:

```
public class Lists {
    public static <T> List<T> toListArray(T[] arr){
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T elt : arr)
            list.add(elt);
        return list;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> toListVarargs(T... arr){
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T elt : arr)
            list.add(elt);
        return list;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = Lists.<Object>toListVarargs(1, "two");
        list = Lists.<Object>toListVarargs();
        list = Lists.<Object>toListArray(1,"two");//<---Does not compile
        list = Lists.<Object>toListArray();//<---Does not compile
    }
}
```

Why first two strings in main compiles and the last two do not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does not compile:

```
list = Lists.<Object>toListArray(1,"two");//<---Not compiles
list = Lists.<Object>toListArray();//<---Not compiles
```

because `toListArray()` expects ***exactly one*** argument (and it has to be an array). You are trying to pass 0 or 2 arguments, thus the error (only varargs allows arbitary nummber of arguments)

Answer (score 2):

Because toListArray expects an array as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The last two don't compile because the compiler expects an array as input argument for the method (`toListArray`). In contrast, `toListVarargs` is based on varargs so it can take zero, one or more arguments of *any* type (since you used the `Object` type).